# why do we get AssertionFailedError?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have the following piece of code:

```
        TableViewer tv = new TableViewer(attributeTable);
        tv.setContentProvider(new BOAttributeTableContentProvider());
        tv.setLabelProvider(new BOAttributeTableLabelProvider());
```

where while setting the label provider i am getting `AssertionFailedError`. can anybody tell me what wrong i am doing here? or in which case it throws this error?

error Log:

```
org.eclipse.jface.util.Assert$AssertionFailedException: null argument;
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.disassociate(StructuredViewer.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer.internalRefreshAll(TableViewer.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer.internalRefresh(TableViewer.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer.internalRefresh(TableViewer.java:807)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$7.run(StructuredViewer.java:1388)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1323)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1386)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setLabelProvider(ContentViewer.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setLabelProvider(StructuredViewer.java:2003)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer.setLabelProvider(TableViewer.java:1086)
    at com.misys.bankfusion.bpdesigner.boeditor.pages.BOAttributesPage.populateAttributeTableContents(BOAttributesPage.java:458)
    at com.misys.bankfusion.bpdesigner.boeditor.pages.BOAttributesPage.access$000(BOAttributesPage.java:128)
    at com.misys.bankfusion.bpdesigner.boeditor.pages.BOAttributesPage$1.setToModel(BOAttributesPage.java:341)
    at com.trapedza.bankfusion.editor.AbstractEditorDelegate.updateData(AbstractEditorDelegate.java:173)
    at com.trapedza.bankfusion.editor.AbstractEditorDelegate$1.dialogFieldChanged(AbstractEditorDelegate.java:181)
    at com.trapedza.bankfusion.utils.dialogs.internal.DialogField.dialogFieldChanged(DialogField.java:132)
    at com.trapedza.bankfusion.utils.dialogs.internal.ListBoxDialogField.doModifySelection(ListBoxDialogField.java:51)
    at com.trapedza.bankfusion.utils.dialogs.internal.ComboDialogField$2.widgetSelected(ComboDialogField.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:928)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3348)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:2968)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:1930)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:1894)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEApplication.run(IDEApplication.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)
```

Comment: I left my crystal ball in my other pants

Comment: An error trace would be helpful - AssertionFailedError is a junit class, does this happen during a test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructor that you are using (`TableViewer`) or two setters (`setContentProvider`, `setLabelProvider`) have guarding [`assert`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) statements which are throwing these exceptions. Author of the code had an idea to protect its code from irregular parameters that you are using when invoking her/his code.

Comment: `AssertionFailedError` is a JUnit thing, not a java `assert` thing.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the "test" at the beginning of the method name is lower case. If you say TestMethod you will get this error message. You should say testMethod.

For example:

```
@Test
    public void test_VPlugin() throws Exception {
```

This works for me and I hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace shows that your call to *'TableViewer.setLabelProvider()'* from *'BOAttributesPage.populateAttributeTableContents()'* eventually results in call to *'org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.disassociate()*' with *null* argument and that method constraints input argument to be not-*null*.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like BOAttributeTableContentProvider provides a null object somewhere along line (one of the elements you are trying to display in the table is null).
Debug the content provider. Hope my late answer will help.